# Rails No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen. Can`t get file content from uploads directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file, carrierwave

I have saved svg icon with carrierwave, and try to place svg in layout? but I get error "not such file". How I can make this?

helper

```
def show_svg(path)
  File.open(Rails.root.join(path), "rb") do |file|
    raw file.read
  end
end
```

view

```
-@socLinks.each do |link|
      %a{:href => link.link}
        =show_svg link.icon_url.to_s
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked for me

```
def svg(path)
  file_path = "#{Rails.root}/public#{path}"
  return File.read(file_path).html_safe if File.exists?(file_path) '(not found)'
end

=svg link.icon_url.to_s
```